# Problems with CComQIPtr reference counting used in threads

Tags: c++, multithreading, com

I have a program that makes intensive use through **threads** of local `ComQIPtr` to member variables also `ComQIPtr`, for example (very simple):

```
class dummy
{
public:
 (some code)

    void calledFromThreads ()
    {
        if (m_memberVar.getType()==1)
        {
            CComQIPtr<type2> localVar(m_memberVar);
            (more code)
        }
    }

private:
    CComQIPtr<type1> m_memberVar;

};
```

After intensive use, sometimes in the `if (m_memberVar.getType()==1)` line, an exception is raised.

After debugging, I see that the pointer indicates **0xdddddd** (deleted memory), and after another execution, having put a memory breakpoint in `m_memberVar` memory position, I see that is being released when leaving the `if (m_memberVar.getType()==1)` block, when destroying `CComQIPtr<type2> localVar(m_memberVar)`.

This, IMHO, **should never happen** in theory, because when the `CComQIPtr` is created it already makes an `AddRef` internally, so the `Release` when the `CComQIPtr` is destroyed should not affect it (it is a +1 and then a -1), even if there are multiple simultaneous accesses to the same function, there is always an addition before the subtraction.

But the fact is that it happens (occasionally and randomly), and in several parts of the code (it makes use of `CComQIPtr` in many parts), and I don't understand why.

Comment: You are make some assumptions that may or may not be true: 1) the COM object implements refcounting properly to begin with, 2) you don't have some other bug in your code that is randomly overwriting `m_memberVar` unexpectedly (buffer overflow, etc), 3) the `dummy` object and thus its `m_memberVar` member, are not being destructed while `calledFromThreads()` is running, thus releasing `m_memberVar` before `CComQIPtr` can `AddRef` it.

Comment: 1) I assume that yes, COM implements RefCount correctly.
2) I have considered this possibility, but it is not the case: I have checked memory, changed position objects, etc.
3) The object is alive during the whole execution.

Comment: 1) individual COM objects, not COM itself, implement the recounting. 2) so, you can verify with 100% certainty, that the `type1*` pointer held in `m_memberVar` does not change value when the crash happens? Because it should not be changing value, even if the underlying `type` object is destroyed. 3) if recounting is accurate, and `m_memberVar` is not being destroyed or corrupted, then what you describe is simply not possible. You are going to have to put a data breakpoint on the held `type1*` pointer and look at the call stack if/when it actually changes value unexpectedly.

Comment: Reviewing the code, I see that the COM class inherits from CComSingleThreadModel instead of CComMultiThreadModel.
I think that's going to be the problem...

Comment: https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/17837/Global-Interface-Table-An-Easy-Way-to-Marshal-an-I